# Abaqus Scripting: Finding a varying number of faces using findat

Tags: python, scripting, tuples

I'm trying to run a parametric study using Abaqus scripting. It's going to create a shell geometry and then partition it a varying number of times depending on how many times I specify.

My problem is that I'm trying to apply a centrifugal force and to do that I have to find all faces in the part. Is there a simple way to select a whole part? Its easy to calculate a coordinate system for each face, but I'm having trouble trying to combine them all into a value that Abaqus accepts.

Abaqus requires the coordinates to specified as follows, ((x1,y1,z1),), ((x2,y2,z2),)......... ((xn,yn,zn),)

I have been trying to use a while loop (shown below) to create a tuple with the coordinates but it does not like the extra set of brackets put either side. It also won't accept a string.

```
El = 1      #Used as a counter for how many partitions
allFaceCoords = ()

while El <= NumOfElLength:      
    regionCentreSpan = (Length/NumOfElLength)*0.5+((El-1)*(Length/NumOfElLength)) # Creates z coord
    regionCentre = (CentreLineXCord, 0.0, regionCentreSpan) # Put x,y,z coords in one value

    faceCoords =((regionCentre),)   # Abaqus wants each repeating unit as ((x,y,z),)
    allFaceCoords = allFaceCoords + (faceCoords,) # To add all the coordinates into 1 tuple

    El=El+1

facesAll = faces.findAt((allFaceCoords,))
```

Any ideas how I could achieve this would be much a appreactiated.

Cheers, Matt

Answer (score 1):

try using the commands:

mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['part_name'].faces.getBoundingBox(,,,)

or

mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['skt_R_board'].faces.getByBoundingSphere(

or

mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['skt_R_board'].faces.index[#]

Comment: Hi sorry for taking so long to get back to you. So essentially I could  create a set using all faces using something along the the lines of the following (I'm getting error where Abaqus just shuts down).

allFaces = mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Blade_Model'].faces.getByBoundingSphere( (0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ), (2.0),)
assembly.Set(faces=allFaces, name='All Faces')

Comment: if you truley want all of the faces you might be better off just grabbing that objustct directly with some like:

mdb.models.parts['name'].faces.keys()